# Laravel Eloquent multiple joins

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to load all stores from database, with store address and city details.

**stores**

- store_id
- name
- description

**store_address**

- store_id
- street
- zip
- city_id

**cities**

- city_id
- name

I have managed to load all stores with address, but I'm having problems with loading city name by city id.

This is what I'm currently getting:

```
{
   "store_id":1,
   "name":"Store Name",
   "description":"Store description",
   "created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
   "updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
   "address":{
      "store_id":1,
      "street":"Street name",
      "zip":00000,
      "city_id":1
   }
}
```

My code:

```
$stores = Store::with('address')->get();

class Store extends Eloquent
{

    protected $table = 'stores';
    protected $primaryKey = 'store_id';

    public function address(){
        return $this->hasOne('StoreAddress', 'store_id');
    }
}

class StoreAddress extends Eloquent
{

    protected $table = 'store_address';
    protected $primaryKey = 'store_id';

}
```

So I just need to get city name from city table by city_id, I could not find example of this what I'm trying to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create the `belongsTo` city relationship into the `StoreAddress` model.

You need something like this:

```
class StoreAddress extends Eloquent
{

    protected $table = 'store_address';
    protected $primaryKey = 'store_id';

    public function city()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('City', 'city_id');
    }

}
```

Ofcourse, you need to create a model for the city (if you have not done it yet).

Comment: Thanks, I was doing already similar to this, but had me a while to understand how to call city() in query that gets stores.